# merge rows by subject number

Tags: r, merge, rows, reshape

What I am trying to do is merge my dataframe by rows. For instance let's say my data.frame is called data and it looks like this: I have 5 columns- subject contains 5s and 6s, Phase contains Post-Lure and Pre-Lure, Type contains Visual and Auditory and Memory contains a list of scores. Ex:

```
      Subject     Phase        Type             Memory
1         5     Post-Lure     Visual          0.80000000
2         5     Post-Lure     Auditory        0.70666667
3         5     Pre-Lure      Visual          0.40000000
4         5     Pre-Lure      Auditory        0.61333333
5         6     Post-Lure     Visual          0.80000000
6         6     Post-Lure     Auditory        0.54666667
```

As you can see from the code above, the subject is repeated (subject 5 is the same person but the phase and/or type are now different). Thus, I am looking for a code that will make all of the data for each subject on the same row. Hence, the memory scores, and the different types and phases each subject were exposed to will just now become additional columns on the same row. I feel aggregate may do the trick but is it possible to use that code without applying a function to each of the numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to add an "indicator" variable of some sort (for example, how many "times" there are for each subject).

That can be done with `ave` and `seq_along`:

```
mydf$time <- with(mydf, ave(Subject, Subject, FUN=seq_along))
```

Next, you can use `reshape()` to go from "long" to "wide".

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", 
        idvar="Subject", timevar="time")
#   Subject   Phase.1 Type.1 Memory.1   Phase.2   Type.2  Memory.2
# 1       5 Post-Lure Visual      0.8 Post-Lure Auditory 0.7066667
# 5       6 Post-Lure Visual      0.8 Post-Lure Auditory 0.5466667
#    Phase.3 Type.3 Memory.3  Phase.4   Type.4  Memory.4
# 1 Pre-Lure Visual      0.4 Pre-Lure Auditory 0.6133333
# 5     <NA>   <NA>       NA     <NA>     <NA>        NA
```

---

If you wanted to use the "reshape2" or "tidyr" packages, you would first have to get the data into a "long" form using `melt` or `gather`, but note that in the process, your variable types would be converted since a single column would be containing several data types.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to reshape your data? The question isn't clear. Let's call your dataframe `df`. Then

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Subject ~ Phase + Type)
```

will produce

```
  Subject Post-Lure_Auditory Post-Lure_Visual Pre-Lure_Auditory Pre-Lure_Visual
1       5          0.7066667              0.8         0.6133333             0.4
2       6          0.5466667              0.8                NA              NA
```